# Create all possible subtree of a tree in java

Tags: java, recursion, tree, graphviz

I have a generic tree and I want to generate all possible subtrees from it.
Example (the values in the nodes are random):

```
          0 
        / | \ 
       1  2  4
          |  
          3
```

The possible output will be:

```
(0)
(0,1)(0,2)(0,4)(0,2,3)
(0,1,2) (0,2,4) (0,1,2,3) (0,1,2,4) (0,2,3,4) 
(0,1,2,3,4)
```

I add that I pass a tree object that contains a list of nodes and edges, and then print with graphviz. Example :

```
List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>(); // [0,1,2,3,4]
List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<>(); // [(0,null), (0,1), (0,2), (2,3), (0,4)]

Tree tree = new Tree(nodes,edges); 
// this is an example of a tree that I pass as a parameter
```

I'm trying to do a recursive method, but the edges I pass can be random, as can the nodes. I only know the root node, which is in the first edge [(0, null)]

thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I've only tested this on your single example, but it seems to work.

```
public class Subtree
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Subtree app = new Subtree ();
        app.test ();
    }

    private void test ()
    {
        Node[] nodes = {new Node (0), new Node (1), new Node (2), new Node (3), new Node (4)};
        nodes[0].connect (nodes[1], nodes[2], nodes[4]);
        nodes[2].connect (nodes[3]);

        List<Node> result = subtrees (nodes[0], 0);
        for (Node tree : result)
        {
            System.out.printf ("Result Subtree %s %n", tree);
        }
    }

    private List<Node> subtrees (Node root, int traceLevel)
    {
        System.out.printf ("%s Subtrees from %s %n", "  |".repeat (traceLevel), root);
        List<Node> result = new ArrayList<> ();
        // Add a result for the root node with no children
        result.add (new Node (root.id));
        List<List<Node>> nextLevel = new ArrayList<> ();
        for (Node child : root.children)
        {
            // Form all subtrees of each direct child
            nextLevel.add (subtrees (child, traceLevel + 1));
        }
        result.addAll (formSubtrees (root.id, nextLevel, 0));
        System.out.printf ("%s => %s %n", "  |".repeat (traceLevel), result);
        return result;
    }

    private List<Node> formSubtrees (int rootId, List<List<Node>> nextLevel, int i)
    {
        List<Node> result = new ArrayList<> ();
        if (i < nextLevel.size ())
        {
            List<Node> remainder = formSubtrees (rootId, nextLevel, i + 1);
            for (Node n : nextLevel.get (i))
            {
                Node t0 = new Node (rootId);
                t0.connect (n);
                result.add (t0);
                for (Node r : remainder)
                {
                    Node t = new Node (rootId);
                    t.connect (n);
                    for (Node c : r.children)
                    {
                        t.connect (c);
                    }
                    result.add (t);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class Node
{
    int id;

    List<Node> children = new ArrayList<> ();

    Node (int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void connect (Node... nodes)
    {
        for (Node n : nodes)
        {
            children.add (n);
        }
    }

    public String toString ()
    {
        final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder ();
        buffer.append ("[");
        buffer.append (getClass ().getSimpleName ());
        buffer.append (" ");
        buffer.append (id);
        for (Node n : children)
        {
            buffer.append (" ");
            buffer.append (n);
        }
        buffer.append ("]");
        return buffer.toString ();
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
= Subtrees from [Node 0 [Node 1] [Node 2 [Node 3]] [Node 4]] 
=  | Subtrees from [Node 1] 
=  | => [[Node 1]] 
=  | Subtrees from [Node 2 [Node 3]] 
=  |  | Subtrees from [Node 3] 
=  |  | => [[Node 3]] 
=  | => [[Node 2], [Node 2 [Node 3]]] 
=  | Subtrees from [Node 4] 
=  | => [[Node 4]] 
= => [[Node 0], [Node 0 [Node 1]], [Node 0 [Node 1] [Node 2]], [Node 0 [Node 1] [Node 2] [Node 4]], [Node 0 [Node 1] [Node 2 [Node 3]]], [Node 0 [Node 1] [Node 2 [Node 3]] [Node 4]]] 
Result Subtree [Node 0] 
Result Subtree [Node 0 [Node 1]] 
Result Subtree [Node 0 [Node 1] [Node 2]] 
Result Subtree [Node 0 [Node 1] [Node 2] [Node 4]] 
Result Subtree [Node 0 [Node 1] [Node 2 [Node 3]]] 
Result Subtree [Node 0 [Node 1] [Node 2 [Node 3]] [Node 4]
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but i was trying to solve the problem by myself. Your code helped me, even if the following edges are not generated: (0,2), (0,4), (0,2,3), (0,2,4), (0, 2,3,4).
I improved my code by adding in the node class the list of all the children of each single node, and its father node, and I'm looking for a solution. Anyway, thank you very much for your help